# javascript - regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to form a regular expression to match the pattern of keywords, the pattern I found  is like

- remove all words before `:` till a space occurs and all words after `:` till `)` occurs.

find the term in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvUaK/141).

```
var newInput="keyword2:(content2) app keyword1:(content1) sos keyword:(content) das sad";
```

Im looking for an output like

```
app,sos,das,sad
```

Comment: Does it have to be regular expressions? You could just split by space and filter items that start with 'keyword'..

Comment: it doesnt have to be the term keyword... it could be random words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newInput.replace(/[^:\s]+:\([^)]*\)\s*/g, '');  // "app sos das sad"
```

Explanation

```
[^:\s]+:   # any character (except ' ' and ':') in front of ':'  "keyword1:'"
\([^)]*\)  # any character enclosed in '(' ')'                   "(content2)"
\s*        # trailing spaces                                     " "
```

This returns a space-separated string. You would have to trim it and split at spaces (or replace them) yourself.

Comment: check the input "keyword2:(content2) app keyword1:(content1)";

Comment: @Sam Next time, do a better job at defining your inputs. With regular expression questions the answer can only be as good as the question is.

Comment: No. In your question a "searched word" always appears after a `keyword:(contents)` pattern.

Comment: "keyword2:(content2)"  and "app" can come in any order

Comment: That's what I mean. Regex are extremely specific, so you must be extremely specific when stating your possible inputs. Otherwise you'll force people to guess, which is never a good thing. See modified answer. -- BTW, my answer was 99% of the way even with your more specific requirements. You could have made the last adjustment yourself, if you had tried.

Comment: I am sorry about that mistake..I am new to regular expression so finding a bit hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var words = newInput.replace(/[^\s]+:\([^\)]+\)\s+/g, "").split(/\s+/);
```

Which will produce an array of the words as:

```
["app", "sos", "das", "sad"]
```

If you want a comma-separated string as shown in the question then:

```
var words = newInput.replace(/[^\s]+:\([^\)]+\)\s+/g, "").split(/\s+/).join(", ")
```

Comment: check the input "keyword2:(content2) app keyword1:(content1)";

Comment: OK, sorry. I admit I found your description in the question a bit confusing, and you didn't show an example like that, but I guess you could change the regex pattern to `/[^\s]+:\([^\)]+\)\s*/g` (i.e., change the last `+` to a `*` to match optional whitespace), and then trim whitespace from the result.